# How do I get my pythonanywhere to make changes on my web page after doing git pull?

Tags: django, git, git-pull, pythonanywhere

I have a problem with updating my code from *GitHub* to *Python Anywhere*. I am following *Django Girls Tutorial*. I've updated some code on my local files and have pushed to GitHub with new commit. I could see the change in my Github repository. Then I tried `git pull` at *Python Anywhere* and I saw this message:

```
Updating ebefb9b..75b3566 error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: blog/templates/blog/base.html blog/templates/blog/post_detail.html blog/views.py mysite/settings.py mysite/urls.py Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: blog/templates/registration/login.html Please move or remove them before you can merge. Aborting.
```

So I tried everything but still it didn’t work until I saw a post here on stackoverflow that suggested, `git reset --hard` before `git pull` and I applied it and it solved the problem but I couldn’t see changes on my web page. I can only see the Django installation success web page. I have done reload, refresh everything but still can’t get any help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the changes that you made on *PythonAnywhere* were part of the tutorial and that you removed those changes when you ran `git reset --hard`. You'll have to try to work out which changes you lost and re-do them from the tutorial.

Comment: Is working now! I didn’t know that I had to press a button to reload it. I was thinking that clicking refresh button was same as reloading.